# How to know what number a system call has in linux

Tags: linux, numbers, system, call, unistd.h

So I need to know what number a certain system call has , it says that I can check which number a systemcall has in unistd.h file but how/where can I find that file?

Answer (score 0):

Probably under `/usr/include/`...

Try `find /usr/include/ -name unistd.h`, assuming you're actually developing on a linux box!

That will list a bunch of platform-specific variants, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal type command `find /usr/include -name unistd.h` this gets you location of unistd.h in your system. Probably it will have some inclusions in `/usr/include/bits` and other subdirectories.